# Load a struct from a string

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

I have a string with the following format:

```
Surname(7characters) Name(7characters) ID(8characters) Salary(5characters)
```

I want to load it into a struct employee:

```
typedef struct{
    char surName[20];
    char name[20];
    long int id;
    int salary;
}employee;

void loadEmployee(employee *empl,char line[]){
    char *aux=line+strlen(line);
    *aux='\0';
    aux-=6;
    sscanf(aux+1,"%d",&empl->salary);

    *aux='\0';
    aux-=9;
    sscanf(aux+1,"%ld",&empl->id);

    *aux='\0';
    aux-=8;
    sscanf(aux+1,"%s",empl->name); //!!!!ERROR

    *aux='\0';
    sscanf(line,"%s",empl->surname);//!!!!ERROR
}

int main(){
    employee empl;
    loadEmployee(&empl,"Friedman John     37243365 50000");
    return 0;
}
```

The error says char format pointer arg. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1)`char* surName[20];` --> `char surName[20];` 2)`empl->surname` --> `empl->surName`

Comment: After correcting the declarations (plural) in `employee`, you may wish to use `if (sscanf (line, "%19s %19s %ld %d", emp1->surname, emp1->name, &(emp1->id), &(emp1->salary)) == 4) {...}` or **tokenize** the string with, e.g. `strtok` and copy/convert as required.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I fixed that and it is giving the same error.

Comment: 3) `*aux='\0';` : The string literal can not be changed. `loadEmployee(&empl, "Friedman Jhon     37243365 50000");` --> `loadEmployee(&empl, (char[]){"Friedman Jhon     37243365 50000"});`

Comment: 4) `Friedman` and `Jhon    ` are **8**charachers

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks! it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment, you can greatly simplify your `loadEmployee` function (and improve your validation by having it provide a meaningful **return** type that can be checked for success/failure) by parsing the string in a single call and returning a pointer of `NULL` on failure, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char surname[20];
    char name[20];
    long int id;
    int salary;
} employee;

employee *loadEmployee (employee *empl, char *line)
{
    if (sscanf (line, "%19s %19s %ld %d", 
        empl->surname, empl->name, &(empl->id), &(empl->salary)) == 4)
        return empl;

    return NULL;
}

int main (void) {

    employee empl;

    if (loadEmployee (&empl, "Friedman Jhon     37243365 50000"))
        printf ("empl.name: %s\nempl.surname: %s\n"
                "empl.id: %ld\nempl.salary: %d\n",
                empl.name, empl.surname, empl.id, empl.salary);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stringstruct
empl.name: Jhon
empl.surname: Friedman
empl.id: 37243365
empl.salary: 50000
```